# Golang: select few million rows from PostgreSQL database using readable streams like in node.js

Tags: node.js, postgresql, go

I have PostgreSQL table with ~ 50 million rows, I want to write Go code to select ~ 1 million rows from this table, and process them in efficient way.

Previous time i used nodejs and this NPM module [pg-query-stream](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pg-query-stream) to generate readable stream of records found, so i can process them like any readable object stream.

Here I post simplified code I used to process data:

```js
const pg = require('pg');
const QueryStream = require('pg-query-stream');

 
//pipe 1,000,000 rows to stdout without blowing up your memory usage
pg.connect((err, client, done) => {
  if (err) throw err;
  const query = new QueryStream('SELECT * FROM generate_series(0, $1) num', [1000000]);
  const stream = client.query(query);
  //release the client when the stream is finished
  stream.on('end', done);
  stream.on('data', function(data) { 
    stream.pause();
    funcDoSomethingWithDataAsync(data, function(error) {
      if(error) throw error;
      stream.resume();
    });
 };
})
```

How can I emulate readable stream of database records in Go? Does [sql.Scanner](https://godoc.org/database/sql#Rows.Scan) in Go works with streaming query results like nodejs module does?

I already have optimized queries that works ok, I just want to stream query execution result to Go, like its done in nodejs library.

Comment: are you performing computations in the iterations? how long does iterating over 1 million rows take you? I am having same issue and iterating over 10,000 rows is taking like 20 minutes to complete...trying to reduce that

Comment: Even better way to stream lots of records in NodeJS - [pg-iterator](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-iterator).

Answer (score 12):

Yes, it works very much the same: execute the query, iterate through the results. Here's a simple example using [lib/pq](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/lib/pq) which is the Postgres version of [database/sql](https://pkg.go.dev/database/sql).

Make the [Query](https://pkg.go.dev/database/sql#DB.Query) and then iterate through the [Rows](https://pkg.go.dev/database/sql#Rows).

```
rows, err := db.Query(`SELECT * FROM generate_series(0, $1) num`, 1000000)
if err != nil {
   panic(err)
}
 
defer rows.Close()
for rows.Next() {
    var num int
 
    err = rows.Scan(&num)
    if err != nil {
       panic(err)
    }
 
    fmt.Println(num)
}
```

Comment: as far as i understand how `github.com/lib/pg` works, it saves all query result in RAM, and then parses it with `rows.Next` - it seems to consume a lot of RAM, instead of streaming nodejs library. I'm gratefull for answer, but i cannot consider this as answer yet.

Comment: No, it has a buffer to fetch some of the results to avoid doing a network call for each row. Try it with various sizes of series and check your memory usage, it should remain constant.

Comment: i'll try your code with profiler and provide result here, it will save me a lot of effort, if it works like this

Comment: @vodolaz095 Stick a sleep in the loop, run it with 10 vs 10000000 numbers, and compare the memory size.

Comment: Hey @vodolaz095 what's your conclusion?

Answer (score 4):

I observed memory usage of Go program which uses lib/pq:

- When the result set returned is 0 or 1 row, memory used is around 15MB
- When result set has 50K rows (each of 200bytes, amount to 10MB). I put sleep while looping through results but memory increase was only 2 MB.
  Even with multiple such heavy requests memory rose by few MBs

So Schwern is correct that pq maintains buffer for reading results.